# Blacklist the "developing" tag

Tags: support, tags

May [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing) be blacklisted?

The tag doesn't anything to the question, as there is very little difference between code being developed for a module, and code required from a module that allows the users (whatever they have an administrative account, or not) to enter code in a text area: In both the cases, the API offered from Drupal is the same, and the same functions can be used in both the cases.

There are eventually differences between developing a module, and a theme, but in most of the cases, the same functions can be called from a module, or a theme. There are differences between the hooks a theme can implement, but that is merging for the question: As long as it is clear the question is about the code to use in a theme, there is no need to use [developing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developing), which would not allow to make a difference between developing a theme, and developing a module.

The tag has been used in 33 questions:

- 4 questions were asked in June
- 15 questions were asked in the current year
- 30 questions were asked between June, 2012 and September, 2011

Comment: +1 It's completely ambiguous, no use to anyone really

Comment: No one has missed this tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a very low-volume tag and I don't see great support here to blacklist it.

If it becomes widespread and overwhelming, we can revisit this.